# Get all Alfresco users (from Java AMP)

Tags: alfresco

I want to get the usernames (Strings) of all users in Alfresco.

My code is running as an AMP within Alfresco itself.

How to do that?

---

I tried using [PersonService](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/org/alfresco/service/cmr/security/PersonService.html#getPeople-java.lang.String-java.util.List-java.util.List-org.alfresco.query.PagingRequest-) but it outputs no results, even though I have several users in Alfresco (created via the Share admin interface):

```
RunAsWork runAsWork = new RunAsWork() {
    @Override
    public Object doWork() throws Exception {
        return personService.getPeople("*", null, null, new PagingRequest(1000));
    }
};
PagingResults<PersonInfo> results =
    (PagingResults<PersonInfo>) AuthenticationUtil.runAsSystem(runAsWork);

System.out.println("Number of users: " + results.getTotalResultCount());
while (results.hasMoreItems()) {
    for (PersonInfo info : results.getPage()) {
        System.out.println("User: " + info.getUserName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
PersonService personService = documentService.serviceRegistry.getPersonService();
PagingResults<PersonInfo> users = personService.getPeople("*", new ArrayList<QName>(), new ArrayList<Pair<QName,Boolean>>(), new PagingRequest(personService.countPeople()));
logger.info("The number of users in the system" + personService.countPeople());
do {
        List<PersonInfo> personInfos = users.getPage();
        for(PersonInfo personInfo : personInfos) {
            logger.info("User Name: " + personInfo.getUserName());
        }
} while(users.hasMoreItems());
```

This code will log all the users in alfresco

Answer (score 0):

The people api returns list of users

```
http://server:port/alfresco/service/api/people
```

or try this by injecting
   `serviceRegistry`

```
try {


                    Set<String> authorities = serviceRegistry.getAuthorityService().getAllAuthorities(AuthorityType.USER);


                    for (String authority : authorities) {
                        NodeRef person = serviceRegistry.getPersonService().getPerson(authority);

                        Map<QName, Serializable> properties = serviceRegistry.getNodeService().getProperties(person);

                        String fullName=properties.get(ContentModel.PROP_FIRSTNAME) +" "+properties.get(ContentModel.PROP_LASTNAME); 
                        System.out.println("User Full Name "+fullName);

                    }       

            } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I would rather avoid using an HTTP API to avoid having to store passwords. Thanks for the Java code though!

Answer (score 0):

It might be an issue with the authentication from your amp, you may try this:
(PagingResults) AuthenticationUtil.runAs(runAsWork, AuthenticationUtil.getSystemUserName());

It is the same thing as you did but I had trouble with runAsSystem before on an old repo. Else there are more way of messing up with the person service here [PersonService.PersonInfo](http://programtalk.com/java-api-usage-examples/org.alfresco.service.cmr.security.PersonService.PersonInfo/)